# Slow export in Flash Professional CS6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6, away3d

I have linked an external library to my fla from the advanced publish settings. (It is away3d library)

There is nothing on the stage and nothing on the timeline either, I have just added some code in the Document Class(look below).

Whenever I run the code below without the line: `private _view:View3D` it exports fast in about a few seconds, but when I keep that line, it exports very slowly, in about 1 minute.

How can I make the export fast while using external libraries.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.geom.Vector3D;
    import away3d.primitives.PlaneGeometry;
    import away3d.containers.View3D;
    import away3d.entities.Mesh;
    import flash.events.Event;

public class Main extends Sprite
{
    private var _view:View3D;
    //whenever I comment this line out, it exports fast

    public function Main()
    {
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
    }
}
}
```

EDIT: Here is the image of the way I linked the away3d library to my fla - https://i.stack.imgur.com/poH5Y.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you link source path Flash IDE compiles all classes each time you publish your application, to prevent this link swc file (that contains away3d classes) in the Library path section.

Comment: hi fsbmain, i download swc version from the away3d website and linked it, but it still is very slow

Comment: solved it, i forgot to remove the src path that I was using earlier . thanks a bunch, great answer